# Condition in eager loading Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, eager-loading, eloquent

I have the following tables

1. Purchases
2. Products
3. Sales

and following relations

1. Purchase has many products
2. Sale Has many products
3. Product has many sales
4. Product belongs to purchase

I want to get the sold products of a purchase. so my query was like this

```
$purchase = Purchases::with(['product','product.sale' => function ($query){
                return $query->where('status','complete');
            }])->find($request->id);
```

My question is the status is getting checked in the sales table? If it's not then is there any way without using raw query I can check the following condition in sales table?

Answer (score 0):

you can solve it as the following:

```
$purchase = Purchases::with('product')->whereHas('product.sale',function ($query){
            $query->where('status','complete');
        })->find($request->id);
```

Comment: That won't work as the OP wants.This will return a purchase only if it has products sold - if no products were sold, $purchase will be NULL. OP seems to always want a Purchase, but then load only sold products.

Comment: no, It doesn't... It still returns all products for purchases that have at least one sold product ;)

Answer (score 0):

The constraints you apply to the **$query** object are used when related models are retrieved from a relation. In the code above you apply the constraints when **sale** relation is retrieved. So as a result you'll get:

- Purchase with id **$request->id**
- **All** related products
- For every related product you'll get **Sale** object, if its status is **complete**

If you only want to get products that have a sale relation with status=complete, you'll need to provide constraints for the **products** relation, not **product.sale**. The following will do the trick:

```
$purchase = Purchases::with(['product' => function($productQuery) {
    $productQuery->whereHas('sale', function($saleQuery) {
        $saleQuery->where('status','complete');
    });
}])->find($request->id);
```